# Close function with (wrtie/read) function for pipe c++

Tags: c++

I try to write program that reads from file ( line by line ) and counts the number of characters that are similar to  the char in the same line before the space ..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
string count ( string C , int size )
{
    int counter=0;
    char word[10] ;
    char ch ;

          for ( int i=0 ; i < size ; i++ )
          { 
               if ( C[i] == ' ' )
               {

                  for ( int j=i-1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
                  { word[j] = C[j]; } //save the word before the space.

                  ch = C[i+1]; //save the char after the space.
               }
          }

          for ( int z=0 ; z < strlen(word) ; z++ )
          {
              if ( word[z] == ch )
              { counter++ ; }

          }

          stringstream ss;
          ss << counter << endl;
          string newS = ss.str();
          string Result = ch + " " + newS ;

       cout << "The Result:" << Result << endl ;
       return Result;
}

int main()
{
     int pfd[2]; // file disriptors controlling the pipe ends
     pipe(pfd); //create pipe.

     ifstream myfile;
             myfile.open("Things.txt");
             string line;

               while ( !myfile.eof() )
               {
                   getline(myfile,line);
                   cout << line << endl;

                   const char *cstr = line.c_str();

                   close ( pfd[0] ); //close read of pipe.
                   write ( pfd[1] , cstr , strlen(cstr)+1 ); 
                }

              myfile.close();


     int child1 = fork();

     if ( child1 > 0 ) //parent process.
     {
             wait(NULL);



     }
     else if ( child1 == 0 ) //Child 1 process.
     {
             string Str;
             char words[10];
             cout << "hello"<<endl;
             close ( pfd[1] ); //close write pipe1.
             read ( pfd[0] , words , strlen(words)+1 ); //read - pipe1.
             Str = count( words , strlen(words)+1 );//call function count to calculate.
             cout << Str << "****"<< endl;


             int pfd2[2]; //file disriptors controlling the pipe ends.
             pipe(pfd2); //create pipe 2 .

             int child2 = fork();

             if ( child2 > 0 )//parent process.
             {
                 wait(NULL);


                 //close ( pfd2[0] ); //close read of pipe 2. 
                 //write ( pfd2[1] , ,  )

             }
             else if ( child2 == 0 )//child 2 process.
             {
                 //close ( pfd2[1] ); //close write pipe1.
                 //read ( pfd2[0] ,  ,  ); 

                 exit(0);
             }

             else
             { cout << "No Child 2 process! Error in creation" << endl; }


            exit(0);

     } 
     else
     { cout << "No Child 1 process! Error in creation" << endl; }


     return 0 ;
}
```

and this is the file that i want read form :

```
table a

chair i

water t

green e

money m

zebra Z
```

My problem is with close before read/write for pipe , it's not shown anything after it .. and not written anythings after the close function not display.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has a number of problems.

The "close before read" problem is that, in `main`, you close the read end of the pipe *before* the fork.  That means the child process doesn't have a valid file descriptor to read from.  It also means the write (in the main process) is quite likely to go wrong, because there is no way to read the data out of the pipe.

The solution is to move the call to `fork` much higher, and put the code which writes to the pipe inside the `if (child1 > 0)` test (before the wait).

So main will look like:

```
int main()
{
    int pfd[2]; // file disriptors controlling the pipe ends
    pipe(pfd); //create pipe.

    const int child1 = fork();

    if ( child1 > 0 ) //parent process.
    {
        close ( pfd[0] ); // close read of pipe. Only do this once 
                          // - not in the while loop.
        ifstream myfile;
        myfile.open("Things.txt");
        string line;

        while ( !myfile.eof() )
        {
            getline(myfile,line);
            cout << line << endl;

            const char * const cstr = line.c_str();

            write ( pfd[1] , cstr , line.length()+1 ); 
        }

        myfile.close();
    }
    else if ( child1 == 0 ) //Child 1 process.
    {
        char words[10];
        cout << "hello"<<endl;
        close ( pfd[1] ); //close write pipe1.
        read ( pfd[0] , words , sizeof(words)); //read - pipe1.
        string Str = count( words , strlen(words)+1 );//call function count to calculate.
        cout << Str << "****"<< endl;


        int pfd2[2]; //file descriptors controlling the pipe ends.
        pipe(pfd2);  //create pipe 2 .

        int child2 = fork();

        if ( child2 > 0 )//parent process.
        {
            wait(NULL);

            //close ( pfd2[0] ); //close read of pipe 2. 
            //write ( pfd2[1] , ,  )

        }
        else if ( child2 == 0 )//child 2 process.
        {
            //close ( pfd2[1] ); //close write pipe1.
            //read ( pfd2[0] ,  ,  ); 

            exit(0);
        }
        else
        { cout << "No Child 2 process! Error in creation" << endl; }


        exit(0);
     } 
     else
     { cout << "No Child 1 process! Error in creation" << endl; }


     return 0 ;
}
```

In addition to that problem, you use `strlen(word)`, but you never write a terminating `'\0'` after the string.  A better way would be:

```
 size_t wordlen;
 ...
                  wordlen = i;
                  for ( int j=i-1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
                      { word[j] = C[j]; } //save the word before the space.
 ...
          for ( size_t z=0 ; z < wordlen; z++ )
          {
              if ( word[z] == ch )
              { counter++ ; }
          }
```

You will notice I have used `size_t` rather than `int`.  You will find that you get fewer warnings about signed/unsigned comparisons if you do that.  Most index operators return `size_t`, as does `strlen`.

Final comment: Your actual problem would have been a lot more obvious if you had simplified `count` to `return "a 1";` - this is why we ask for a *minimal* example.

Comment: No.  That's because you close the pipe before the fork.  I'll update.

Comment: when i do same what you say , the program print the contains of the file twice .. how can i fix the problem ? and what do you mean about the final comment ?